# Is it possible to group extensions using a namespace in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Adding too many extensions will soon become messy, so grouping extensions under a framework namespace would be ideal.
For example, instead of adding all functions directly to Int like:

```
fun Int.operationA() { 
    println("A $this")
}

fun Int.operationB() { 
    println("B $this")
}

// and use it like:
123.operationA()
123.operationB()
```

I would prefer to use it inside the framework namespace like:

```
123.framework.operationA()
123.framework.operationB()

// Declaring it like this would be nice
fun Int.framework.operationA() { 
    println("A $this")
}
```

In Swift it's possible to accomplish this using protocols and extensions with default implementations.
How about in Kotlin? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't using a package accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IntFramework(val x: Int) {
    fun operationA() ...
    fun operationB() ...
}

// or
class IntFramework(val x: Int)
fun IntFramework.operationA() ...
fun IntFramework.operationB() ...

val Int.framework get() = IntFramework(this)
```

and if you want to add more methods there declare them as extensions on `IntFramework`. But this isn't idiomatic and will likely surprise other developers working with or depending on your code (maybe not those coming from Swift?).

If you only need to support Kotlin 1.3+, you can [make it an `inline class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html) which should remove any overhead compared to defining an extension method on `Int` directly.

Comment: You could make the IntFramework class `inline` here to at least reduce the overhead costs (as of Kotlin 1.3 this feature is still experimental).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! The implementation may look a bit strange, but no one needs to know how it is implemented internally, everyone just need to remember to use .framework. ...

Comment: Actually to achieve this in Swift it's a lot more confusing